# Intuition behind this initialization in Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am solving the following question:

> You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.
>   Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

by constructing the following code snippet:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int climbStairs(int n) {
        if(n==0)
            return 0;

        vector<int> dp(n+1);
        dp[0]=0;
        dp[1]=1;
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2];

        return dp[n];
    }
};
```

When I looked at the solutions, I found out that they make this initialization:

```
dp[0]=0;
dp[1]=1;
dp[2]=2;            //--> Why?  And when to do this?
```

Because of the way I initialized it, I get lower values (like the answer for `n` is at `dp[n-1]` and so on).  All this, just because I didn't initialize `dp[2]=2`.  Could someone please point out the intuition behind this particular initialization?

Thanks!

**Note:** Question is taken from [LeetCode.com](http://www.LeetCode.com).

Comment: An aside: I’ve seen many good tutorials at LeetCode, but also a lot of really poorly-written code or bad examples. It’s healthy to have a little skepticism about what you find there.

Comment: It's fibonacci, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that’s posted here is incorrect, which is why you don’t see dp[2] = 2.

I believe that the DP table here is such that dp[k] represents the number of ways to climb from step n - k to step n using the rules described here. As a result, dp[0] should be 1, not 0. There’s one way to get from step n to step n by following these rules: namely, don’t take any steps!

Once you’ve initialized that value properly, then you’d have dp[2] = dp[0] + dp[1] = 1 + 1 = 2. There’s no need to explicitly initialize dp[2] since the value follows from the general case.